# what the difference between launching application programmatically and double click the app icon manually?

Tags: c#, html, windows, winapi, embed

I am trying to launch an application named `main.exe` using `CreateProcess()`. Although `main.exe` starts, soon it crashes after several error messages which say some DLLs seem corrupted and cannot be executed on Windows OS.

Sorry for the Japanese content in below screen capture, the popup mainly says:

```
**popup title**: the image file of main.exe is not correct.  
**popup content**: mshtml.dll can not be executed on Windows or there is error in this file.
```

Error message after `CreateProcess()`:

[image]

Also, the antivirus seems to get angry:

[image]

The `dummyMain.exe` that the antivirus was angry about in above image was the module that launched `main.exe`.

My code used to launch the app:

```
TCHAR sAppFullPath[] = L"D:\\bin\\main.exe";
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
BOOL bCreateProcess = CreateProcess(sAppFullPath, 
    NULL,// no parameters
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL, 
    &si,
    &m_pi);// m_pi is a member var of class
DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
```

Although may not be useful information: `GetLastError()` above returned 1813 (`ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND`).

With the same usage of `CreateProcess()` above, I can launch other applications without any error.

**One thing that may make `main.exe` special is**:
there is a Internet Explorer server embeded in the main window of it, to show an HTML page.

The `Internet Explorer_Server` identified by Spy++:

[image]

`main.exe` was writen in C# using WPF.

**More information**

The same errors happen after I replace `CreateProcess()` with `ShellExecute()`.

So, the problem seems to reside in the `main.exe` itself.

But I can launch it by double clicking on it without any problem.

The complete list of DLLs that were said to be corrupted and failed to execute were:

```
Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.dll
Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.dll
Windows\system32\Wpc.dll
Windows\system32\MSHTML.dll
Windows\system32\msctfui.dll
```

Before `main.exe` crashed, there was also a file download (the `index.html` to be rendered) dialog appeared which does not respond due to the errors.

[image]

So, I started to suspect the problem is related to the embeeded `Internet Explorer_Server`, but I have no idea what is the difference between launching the application programmatically and double-clicking on it.

**Any hint will be appreciated!**

Comment: _Although the main.exe got started, but the GetLastError() after CreateProcess() was 1813:ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND._ - There is a contradiction. You are saying `CreateProcess()` failed but the "main.exe" got started anyway? That cannot be. On a side note, please include your code *literally* inside the question and format it as *code*. Otherwise it will be impossible for the search function to find it.

Comment: Useless question. If you care to make it useful, include the code that exhibits the error you are experiencing. Also, taking the [tour] ain't optional.

Comment: if  child process started - CreateProcess return true. if CreateProcess return true - not matter what return `GetLastError()` - it usually used only on fail. errors in child process - separate question

Comment: I am SORRY for not taking the tour and posted a bad question. I edited it again.

Comment: When you launch application by double-clicking in most cases explorer arranges current directory to be directory with executable. I also prefer to use `CreateProcess( NULL, full_command_line, ...)` where `full_command_line` includes executable and optionally command arguments (quoted if there is possibility of spaces or other normally not allowed characters).

Answer (score 1):

> Also, the antivirus seems to get angry

Does the error still happen if you disable the antivirus?

> ```
> BOOL bCreateProcess = CreateProcess(sAppFullPath, 
>     NULL,// no parameters
>     NULL,
>     NULL,
>     FALSE,
>     0,
>     NULL,
>     NULL, 
>     &si,
>     &m_pi);// m_pi is a member var of class
> DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
> ```

Calling `GetLastError()` unconditionally is wrong. You should only call `GetLastError()` if `bCreateProcess` is `FALSE`. API functions normally do not reset the last error value in case they are successful, so the last error value may be caused by a previous API call, which would be completely unrelated here.

For maximum compatibility, call `CreateProcess()` with the second argument set to the full command-line. By convention the 1st argument of the command-line is the path of the executable. The C# program may expect that and might fail when you specify no arguments at all.

Also, set the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter to the directory path of the executable. Otherwise the function will use the current directory, which most likely is different from the directory of the application to be launched. A poorly written application may assume that the current directory always equals the application directory on launch.

**Example:**

```
std::wstring const appDirectory = L"D:\\bin\\";
std::wstring const appName = L"main.exe";
std::wstring const appPath = appDirectory + appName;

// In a command-line, all pathes must be enclosed in double quotation marks to prevent 
// space characters in the path from being interpreted as argument separators.
std::wstring appCommandLine = L"\"" + appPath + L"\"";

if( CreateProcessW( NULL, 
    &appCommandLine[0],  // Parameter type is LPWSTR -> we need a pointer to writable data
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0,
    NULL,
    appDirectory.c_str(), 
    &si,
    &m_pi )
{
    // Application launched
}
else
{
    // Application failed to launch. Only here it is valid to call GetLastError()!
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: *For maximum compatibility, call CreateProcess() with the first argument set to NULL* - this is wrong, if we have full path to exe file always better direct use it in first argument. and this absolute not related to compatibility at all. use 0 here exist sense only if we have no exactly path and not want use `SearchPath` yourself.

Comment: @RbMm What sense does it make to specify the path twice if we already specify full path in `lpCommandLine`? Also you leave out 2nd part of sentence when you cite me, which actually *is* important for compatibility: "and the second argument set to the full command-line"

Comment: if we not set explicit *lpApplicationName* - system will be parse *lpCommandLine*, get first token, call `SearchPath` on it (system can not know are we use full or partial path). so really always exist sense explicit use *lpApplicationName* (it this case system will be not touch / parse *lpCommandLine* at all) and main my note was about *For maximum compatibility* - use or not use *lpApplicationName*  have no any effect for compatibility

Comment: @RbMm You should read the documentation more carefully: "If the file name does not contain a directory path, the system searches for the executable file in the following sequence:". And _"system can not know are we use full or partial path"_ - Really? It's trivial to determine if a full or a partial path is specified.

Comment: no, i say that use *lpApplicationName* always have sense and better - in this case system not need **parse** *lpCommandLine* at all. your copy-paste how related here ? it only explain alg of process first token in *lpCommandLine*

Comment: @RbMm In what regard it is "better" to use `lpApplicationName`? The time for parsing `lpCommandLine` is irrelevant compared to the time that is required to launch a new process. Premature optimization at best. In my opinion it is better to have simpler code that is easier to read.

Comment: what is more simpler and more readable code is indefinitely. can be different for different peoples. of course overhead of not using  *lpApplicationName* explicit is relative small. but anyway - if  use *lpApplicationName* is better (we know exactly path and say system use it as is) - why not go by this way. and how i say use or not use *lpApplicationName* not have effect for compatibility. for this have effect only *lpCommandLine*

Comment: @RbMm OK, I have removed that part of sentence.

Comment: ok, i always not understand why frequently programmers not use first parameter of CreateProcess , despite they have full path to executable

Comment: `lpCommandLine` is optional, with no effect at all on compatibility. Omitting it does not mean the process has no command line. It just uses the non-normalized `lpApplicationName` path in quotes as the command line. By non-normalized I mean the path may be relative and use slash instead of backslash as the path separator.

Comment: There's an issue if only `lpCommandLine` is used and the given path is relative and uses slash (e.g. "dir/program.exe"). If `lpApplicationName` isn't used, `SearchPath` is called. Then if the name is relative, `SearchPath` always searches the base search path (from `RtlGetExePath`). Classically this began with the application and current directory, but since Vista the system can be configured to exclude the current directory. The problem is the check in [`NeedCurrentDirectoryForExePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684269) that overrides this only looks for backslash, not slash.